# Windows 8 on Netbook

Tags: netbook, windows-8, resolution

Is there any possibility to force change screen resolution from 800×600 to 1024×768 on  my Samsung NC-10 netbook running Windows 8?

With this resolution I am not able to use any Metro app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah there is one hack in the registry, it only artificially changes the resolution, which does allow you to run Metro apps. Just search the registry for Display1_DownScalingSupported and set all instances you find to 1.